# Загрузка файлов через вк клиент на андроид

Tags: html, vkontakte-api, iframe

Создаю iFrame приложение для Вк, попросили реализовать загрузку фото в альбом. В веб-версии всё работает (как на компьютере, так и на смартфоне), а андроид-приложении "ВК" не открывается окно выбора файлов (поле input - file). Тех.поддержка вк молчит уже четвертые сутки. Кто-то знает, как реализовать?

Comment: Пробовали ли вы в качестве эксперимента создать пустой HTML-документ без стилей и скриптов с одной лишь формой, в которой находится кнопка с выбором файлов?

Comment: да, результат тот же

Comment: У меня такая же проблема. Не нашли случайно решения?

Comment: Написал в службу поддержки вк, там ответили, что передали программистам задание, прошло уже больше двух месяцев, ничего не изменилось